# how can I connect to a different database in Neo4J Browser?

Tags: neo4j

I have `dbms.active_database=debug.db` set in neo4j.conf (and the new database's data directory was created upon restart), but the Neo4J Browser still connects to graph.db

Comment: I'm using Neo4J 3.4.1 Enterprise Edition on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Make sure there’s no other dbms.active_database=graph.db line below your line. And also, make sure your line doesn’t start with # (Just precautionary step)